# Merging cells within a pivot table

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I am trying to merge cells as per the below: [image: Merging cells]

I am hoping to be able to merge them in excel using VBA before they are autocopied into a word document. This will help save my company a lot of time. However, I can't seem to get the coding right.

I have looked on here as well as various forums and the code I am trying to get to work is:

```
    Sub MergeLabels()

Worksheets("Executive Outline").PivotTables(1) _
 .PivotFields("Notes").Orientation = xlRowField

End Sub
```

It runs without any problems but I do not see any results. Is there somewhere I am going wrong?

This is the pivot table I am trying to merge below.

[image: Pivot Table]

Comment: Due to it's dynamic nature, you can't merge pivot table cells.  However you can copy the data elsewhere and do as you wish with it there.

Comment: @ashleedawg I was hoping there might be an even easier method. We are starting to get quite busy so if we can do things more efficiently, that would be useful.

Comment: It's not clear - is that indeed a pivot table? Or are you simply trying to merge cells in a "regular" range?

Comment: @BruceWayne Please see above